# Вывод изображений по шаблону

Tags: android, imageview

Всем доброго времени суток. Кому не сложно, подскажите пожалуйста как устроен вид показа изображений в ВК? Т.е. если одна картинка, то она показана полностью во всю ширину и высоту устройства. Если две картинки, три, четыри и т.д., то образуется симпатичный вид по типу некой сетки... ImageView создаётся у меня программно а загружаются через Picasso. Установлен лимит загрузки до 6 фоток. Очень манит данная реализация) Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Забейте в гугле [pinterest-like-adapterview](https://www.google.ru/search?q=pinterest-like-adapterview&oq=pinterest-like-adapterview&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i60.316j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) - велезает куча проектов с гитхаба, какой понравится больше)

Comment: Ну не куча кончено)) Интересно, получиться ли переделать? Я так понимаю в тех примерах что то типо товарной галлереи. Спасибо за наводку)